# How can I loop through a dataset (from a stored procedure) and check against a single field per row

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, foreach, dataset

I have a dataset dsResult that was filled from a stored procedure. Once I have validated that the dataset is not null and there were rows returned, I want to loop through that ds and check an isActive field to see if any of the rows are active and if any of them are, I will just return the entire dataset.

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables)
            {
                if (dr.["IsActive"] == '1')
                {
                    return  dsResult;
                }
            }
```

1. Am I on the right track with how I would go about doing this? If yes...
2. I get an "identifier expected" error on ["IsActive"] and am unsure of how to resolve it.

Any overall suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column value in a datarow is of type Object.  You need to either do a ToString or cast the object to the correct datatype to do a comparison.

`if (dr["IsActive"].ToString() == "1")`

or

`if ((int)dr["IsActive"] == 1)`

Answer (score 2):

1- This is OK, but maybe will be easier if you use linq to dataset

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx

2- Remove the extra DOT

```
if (dr["IsActive"] == '1')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. When I remove the DOT I get the 'operator == cannot be applied to the operands of type 'object' and 'char'. The IsActive field in the stored procedure results is either '1' or '0'... Do I need to make a cast or something here?

Comment: Changed to 


       foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables)
                {
                    if (dr["IsActive"].Equals('1'))
                    {
                        return  dsResult;
                    }
                }

Comment: @L.Stotch if (dr["IsActive"].ToString() == "1")

Answer (score 0):

May be *Linq* is an easier alternative

```
  // if row["IsActive"] contains char
  if (dsResult.Tables.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => (char)row["IsActive"] == '1'))
    return dsResult;
```

**EDIT**: As I can see from the comment, it's not *character* `1` that's stored in the dataset; the safiest way to get `1` IMHO is to `Convert` when type is unknown

```
  // since we don't know actual type of row["IsActive"] (integer, boolean, string)?
  // we should convert
  if (dsResult.Tables.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["IsActive"]) == 1))
    return dsResult;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I realized the IsActive field being returned from the table is a bit value, which I understand corresponds to Boolean in C#. so I have 
 if (dsResult.Tables.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => (Boolean)row["IsActive"] == true))
                    {
                        return dsResult;
                    }
but the code is not hitting return dsResult; even though dsResult has a row where IsActive contains 'True' - am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @L. Stotch: it depends on *actual value* in the data row; it could be `(row => (bool)row["IsActive"])`, `(row => (int)row["IsActive"] == 1)` or even `(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["IsActive"]) == 1)`

Comment: I tried all three of your examples, and none of them allowed the inside of the conditional statement to be reached. While debugging I looked inside dsResult just before the line that checks IsActive, and verified that there is a row in the dataset, and for that one row the IsActive Column is "True". Any suggestions as to what I might be overlooking?

Comment: Would it perhaps make sense to convert row["IsActive"] to a string and just check if it .equals("True")..?

Comment: Thanks for the help but just FYI I couldn't figure a way to get the Linq approach to work so I went with : foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["IsActive"].ToString() == "True")
                    {
                        return dsResult;
                    }
                }
which seems to be working